# How to implement to send Data to Server

Tags: android

I want to have a data connection that sends every 60 seconds the geo-position.
My problem is how to implement that in my app.

Should i make a service in a endless thread that reads the geo data and send it to my server?
Any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use a service and then use of a handler to post a delay every 60 seconds. Using the

```
postDelayed() method
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using timertask rather than handler. If you use handler it works only for one time,but if you use timertask it works every interval set by you.